# Can I use a laptop charger as a psu for a guitar amp?

Tags: power-supply, ac-dc, guitar-amplifier

My amp is a Blackstar core id 40 and has info in the back that says "Use 16V/3.5A DC Power Supply". I'm confused on this part though if it refers to dc being the input or a dc adapter. Found info about the original PSU and it says that it is an ac adapter. I can't find the original PSU being sold in my country so I tried looking for other alternatives and found a laptop charger that's 16V/4.5A that matches the connector size of the original PSU. From what I've researched, it should be fine as long as it's the same V and wouldn't go less than the required A. I think they're both center pin positive (Can someone please confirm this based on the pictures). I don't know much about electrical stuff so I'm not sure if it's okay to use the laptop charger.

### Guitar Amplifier Info

[image]

### Laptop Charger

[image]

Comment: Most guitar stuff I've come across is centre pin negative, however the picture you show is quite clear that this particular one is centre positive. Do check any other audio/guitar/stage equipment carefully though before assuming. Strictly speaking, that's not a laptop charger, but a laptop power supply. The charger, the thing that carefully monitors the batteries while charging, is in the laptop itself.

Comment: Be sure to insert plug with power off as indicated in manual.

Comment: looks ok to me. if it doesn't work instantly unplug it instantly (just to be safe)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are center-pin positive. If the connector fits, you should be good to go. However, the connector should fit snugly. There are different sizes and both the pin and sleeve need to make good contact.

Comment: Yes, the connector is also 5.5x2.5mm. I've finally tested it on the amp and it's working fine so far. Thank you!